# Return body in OncePerRequestFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Update:
After looking this over with a colleague, this is probably due to the fact that Spring apps run on Tomcat server, which is following standard protocols (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), and will not return a body for HEAD requests.

=====================

I have OncePerRequestFilter designed to reject any HEAD requests, as you can see here:

```
@Component
public class RestrictedResponseFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(httpRequest.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.HEAD.name())){
            resolver.resolveException(httpRequest,httpServletResponse,null,new RequestRejectedException("Http Method HEAD rejected"));
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(httpRequest,httpServletResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

resolver.resolveException sends the request through my ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExceptionHandler.class);

...

    @ExceptionHandler(RequestRejectedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleRequestRejectedException(final RequestRejectedException e, final WebRequest request){
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return handleExceptionInternal(e,null,null,HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN,request);
    }

    private SpringErrorSwaggerDefinition buildResponse(final Exception e, final WebRequest request, final HttpStatus status){
        final SpringErrorSwaggerDefinition cvdosResponse = SpringErrorSwaggerDefinition.builder()
                .message(e.getMessage())
                .timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .error(status.getReasonPhrase())
                .exception(e.getClass().getName())
                .path(request.getContextPath())
                .status(status.value())
                .build();
        return cvdosResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(
            Exception ex, @Nullable Object body, @Nullable HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        final SpringErrorSwaggerDefinition response = buildResponse(ex,request,status);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, status);
    }

}
```

Other Exceptions that are handled in this class return the SpringErrorSwaggerDefinition response body. However, that does not happen when passing through the filter. How can I resolve this?

Comment: So do you mean to say that flow is not reaching `handleRequestRejectedException` method?

Comment: @Jignesh M. Khatri, the flow is reaching the ExceptionHandler, as viewing it in debug mode shows that the flow builds the SpringErrorSwaggerDefinition object, *but* there is no body in the response when I call it in Postman. In other words, all I get is the 403 response code and generic headers.

Comment: Ofcourse it will. You are directly calling a component which is part of the error handling of Spring MVC. However you are only calling the component without that component being called in the scope of Spring MVC (it is called in the scope of a filter way before Spring MVC had a chance to do anything). So the resolver you are calling doesn't do much. The returned `ModelAndView` (normally used to render the response by Spring MVC) is totally ignored.

Comment: @scoll Instead of calling `resolver.resolveException` try throwing the exception directly.

Answer (score 2):

I have a working solution that correctly writes the output of the error to the response body. The difference here is that mine uses caching versions of the request and response which may be related to your issue. The request and response need to be cached for my use-case because the bodies can only be read once.

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    var cachedRequest = new CachedBodyHttpServletRequest(request);
    var wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

    putHeadersInMDC(cachedRequest);

    logRequest(cachedRequest);

    if (!authenticationTokenValid(cachedRequest)) {
        resolver.resolveException(cachedRequest, wrappedResponse, null, new ServiceException(UNAUTHORIZED, UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Unauthorized. \"Authorization\" header must not be blank, must begin with \"Bearer \", must not be expired, and must be valid."));
    } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(cachedRequest, wrappedResponse);
    }

    addResponseHeaders(wrappedResponse);

    logResponse(cachedRequest, wrappedResponse);

    wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();  // IMPORTANT: copy content of response back into original response
}
```

The exception handler is set up like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class ControllerExceptionAdvice {

@ExceptionHandler(value = {ServiceException.class})
public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper<Object>> handleServiceException(ServiceException e) {
    log.error("Got ServiceException {}", e.toString());
    var response = ResponseWrapper.builder()
                                  .code(e.getCode())
                                  .message(e.getMessage())
                                  .build();
    var responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(response, e.getHttpStatus());
    log.error("Returning error response {}", toJson(responseEntity));
    return responseEntity;
}
...
```